# the map dosent's appear also the marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I want to is to have a map and when I set a marker in some position I get it's latitude and longitude... Please tell me what's wrong with my code??

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>geoloaction</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){


 var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(35.6771389,10.0972400);
 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'),{
 zoom:13,
center:latlng,
mapTypeld:google.maps.MapTypeld.ROADMAP });
 var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latlng,
   map:map,
   title:'bougez ce cuseur' ,
   draggable: true });
 var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(){
 setPosition(marker); });
                     return false; });
 function setPosition(marker){
  var pos=marker.getPosition();
 $(document.getElementById('Lat')).val(pos.lat());
   $(document.getElementById('Lng')).val(pos.lng());
 }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="gmap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Does your console say anything?

Comment: show where is #gmap element

Comment: in my local host a white screan appear show nothing

Comment: @sanach check the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/m97o308u/

it is not `MapTypeld` but `MapTypeId`

you should have this line `mapTypeld:google.maps.MapTypeld.ROADMAP` changed to `mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP`

Comment: @sanach please accept my post if it solved your problem